# Return JSON from Postgres with JSON_BUILD_OBJ

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, select

I have a Postgres DB setup, and I'm trying to return a certain data shape back from a query.

My data looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE resource_actions(
resource TEXT NOT NULL,
actions TEXT NOT NULL,
entity TEXT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(resource, actions, entity)
);


INSERT INTO resource_actions (resource, actions, entity) VALUES
('reading-list', 'read', 'Citizen'),
('reading-list', 'read', 'Employee'),
('books', 'read', 'Employee'),
('titles', 'update', 'Citizen'),
('titles', 'read', 'Citizen'),
('titles', 'update', 'Employee'),
('titles', 'read', 'Employee'),
('authors', 'update', 'Employee'),
('authors', 'read', 'Citizen'),
('reviews', 'read', 'Citizen'),
('reviews', 'read', 'Employee'),
('reviews', 'create', 'Citizen'),
('reviews', 'create', 'Employee'),
('employees', 'read', 'Employee'),
('employees', 'read', 'Boss'),
('employees', 'delete', 'Boss'),
('employees', 'create', 'Boss'),
('employees', 'update', 'Boss'),
('employee-schedule', 'read', 'Boss'),
('employee-schedule', 'delete', 'Boss'),
('employee-schedule', 'create', 'Boss'),
('employee-schedule', 'update', 'Boss');
```

I want to return data like so:

```json
{
    read:['Citizen':['reading-list', 'titles', 'authors','reviews'], 'Employee':['books','reading-list', 'titles', 'authors'], 'Boss':[]]
    create:['Citizen':['reviews'], 'Employee':['reviews'], 'Boss':['employees','employee-schedule']],
    update: ['Citizen':['titles'], 'Employee':['authors','titles'], 'Boss':['employees','employee-schedule']],
    delete:['Citizen':[], 'Employee':[], 'Boss':['employees','employee-schedule']]
}
```

I have a SQL query which is close, I just can't for the life of me figure out what I need to change to get the right shape of the data. The query I have is here:

```sql
select actions, 
JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(resource, entity)) AS groupedActions
FROM resource_actions 
GROUP BY actions
```

I have a SQL fiddle showing what I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/93bf5/1/0

It gets me close, but I'm not understanding how to aggregate the data by `entity` and show an array of the resources they have access to. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's not valid json. You have arrays of key-value-pairs, which isn't allowed. Do you want arrays of objects? Or, perhaps, just objects?

Comment: Arrays of objects. I just quickly threw it together the general shape, but you are right it isn't valid json

Comment: Edit your question to fix it then.

Comment: If you check the reply I posted earlier, it is already array of objects. I got yours was just a mockup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select json_build_object(actions, array_agg(groupedResources)) as jsonResult
from (select actions, json_build_object(entity, array_agg(resource)) as groupedResources
      from resource_actions
      group by actions, entity) tmp
group by actions;
```

| jsonresult |
| --- |
| {"create" : [{"Citizen" : ["reviews"]},{"Employee" : ["reviews"]},{"Boss" : ["employees","employee-schedule"]}]} |
| {"read" : [{"Boss" : ["employees","employee-schedule"]},{"Citizen" : ["reading-list","titles","authors","reviews"]},{"Employee" : ["reading-list","books","titles","reviews","employees"]}]} |
| {"update" : [{"Boss" : ["employees","employee-schedule"]},{"Citizen" : ["titles"]},{"Employee" : ["titles","authors"]}]} |
| {"delete" : [{"Boss" : ["employees","employee-schedule"]}]} |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I56W7bb5)

All as single JSON:

```
select json_agg(jsonResult)
from (
select json_build_object(actions, json_agg(groupedResources)) as jsonResult
from (select actions, json_build_object(entity, array_agg(resource)) as groupedResources
      from resource_actions
      group by actions, entity) tmp
group by actions) x;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zAR-JvVC)

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate actions with concatenation you can use a custom aggregation

```
CREATE AGGREGATE json_concat_agg(jsonb) (
  SFUNC = 'jsonb_concat',
  STYPE = jsonb,
  INITCOND = '{}'
);


select json_concat_agg(ga::jsonb)::json
    from (
    select JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(actions, JSON_AGG(ge)) ga
    from (
       select actions, JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(entity, JSON_AGG(resource)) AS ge
       FROM resource_actions 
       GROUP BY actions, entity
    ) t
    group by actions
) t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q09ETPew)

```
{
"read": [{"Boss": ["employees", "employee-schedule"]}, {"Citizen": ["reading-list", "titles", "authors", "reviews"]}, {"Employee": ["reading-list", "books", "titles", "reviews", "employees"]}], 
"create": [{"Citizen": ["reviews"]}, {"Employee": ["reviews"]}, {"Boss": ["employees", "employee-schedule"]}],
"delete": [{"Boss": ["employees", "employee-schedule"]}], 
"update": [{"Boss": ["employees", "employee-schedule"]}, {"Citizen": ["titles"]}, {"Employee": ["titles", "authors"]}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.9.2.2.5.1.2.1) objects in subqueries/[CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)s, then collect them with [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.13.1.2.1): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/isT0qOPf)

```sql
select jsonb_object_agg(actions,entity_resources) result 
from (select actions,
             jsonb_agg(entity_resources) entity_resources
      from (select actions,
                   jsonb_build_object(entity,jsonb_agg(resource)) entity_resources
            from resource_actions 
            group by actions,
                     entity ) innermost_subquery
      group by actions ) subquery;
```

Use [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) if you can: it's indexable, lighter, faster and more flexible, offering more functions and operators, including [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) interaction, at a small processing cost on input.
If you can't, all `jsonb` functions above have direct `json` equivalents they can be swapped out for.

Except for `jsonb_pretty()` below, where you'll have to cast `json` to `jsonb`. If you want to prettify some text-based json, you can feed it as a string literal - it'll be detected as `unknown` and auto-cast to a supported type.

Output through [`jsonb_pretty()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.23.1.1.1):

```json
{
    "read": [
        {
            "Boss": [
                "employees",
                "employee-schedule"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Citizen": [
                "reading-list",
                "titles",
                "authors",
                "reviews"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Employee": [
                "reading-list",
                "books",
                "titles",
                "reviews",
                "employees"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "create": [
        {
            "Citizen": [
                "reviews"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Employee": [
                "reviews"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Boss": [
                "employees",
                "employee-schedule"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "delete": [
        {
            "Boss": [
                "employees",
                "employee-schedule"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "update": [
        {
            "Boss": [
                "employees",
                "employee-schedule"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Citizen": [
                "titles"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Employee": [
                "titles",
                "authors"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're missing one layer of aggregation... https://dbfiddle.uk/CxSbwdpR

Comment: @MatBailie Right, thanks. I overlooked the side-scrolling part of the desired output. Demo and answer edited and corrected accordingly.